# how do I get the User's previous photo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The problem is that previous_modal method is returning the previous photo in the database, not **@user** previous photo.

For example, if @user has photos with id's 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 1  and I open the modal for photo id 6 and I click previous, it sets the href to 5, instead of 1.

```
UsersController

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @photos = @user.photos.approved.order('created_at desc').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 9)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
 end

 users/show.html.erb

 <% @photos.in_groups_of(3, false).each do |group| %>
   <% group.each do |photo| %>
   ...
   <div class="modal" id=<%="#{photo.id}"%> tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   ...
   <a class="previouslink" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" href=<%="#"+"#{photo.previous_modal.id}"%>>
   ...

class Photo 

def previous_modal 
  if self.class.approved.where("id < ?", id).last == nil
    return self
  else
    return self.class.approved.where("id < ?", id).last
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding:

```
.where("user_id" => self.user.id) into the code.
```

Answer (score 1):

On your previous_modal method, instead of searching by id, you could search by created_at... something like:

```
def previous_modal 

  if self.class.approved.where("created_at < ?", self.created_at).last == nil
    return self
  else
    return self.class.approved.where("created_at < ?", self.created_at).last
  end  
end
```

And for a cleaner code, I would suggest:

```
def previous_modal 
  last_photo = self.class.approved.where("created_at < ?", self.created_at).last
  last_photo ? last_photo : self        
end
```

It would work as same as above. Hope it helps!

EDIT:

I'm not sure how you would get that  [ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 1 ] array, but once you have it, it's easy... you just had to find the photo by the id on the next/previous position. Could think of something like:

```
def previous_modal 

    photo_ids = self.user.photos.map(&id) #Get all photos ids for that user
    self_index = photos_ids.index(self.id) #Get the index of this particular object id
    previous_photo = Photo.find_by_id(photos_ids[self_index-1]) #Find the previous one
    return (previous_photo || self)
end
```

But I guess, in this case, the photo_ids returned would be ordered, so produced the same result as above. You have to figure out a way to maintain that array with the history of photos order... good luck!

Comment: This is giving me the same results as my code. It is giving me the previous photo in the database, not `@user`'s previous photo.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. there is not an array. I was just saying that the User has uploaded photos and those photos have those id's. i believe i have solved it. thanks for the help, i still learned a few things from your answer. sorry for poor wording in question.